# Creating models with two words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models one is named BusinessUser and the other is named BusinessPlace.
The BusinessUser can have many BusinessPlaces

```
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :BusinessPlaces
end

class BusinessPlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :BusinessUser
end
```

When i'm trying to access @business_user.BusinessPlaces.count the sql that get build and run on DB is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "business_places"  WHERE "business_places"."business_user_id" = 1
```

but in the migration and in the database the column for business user id is BusinessUser_id which makes the query to fail. Why the sql gets to be build wrong ? I've used the console to create the models.

Comment: How did you build the models? With `rails g ModelName`?

Comment: With rails g model BusinessUser

Comment: People, stop answering on this kind of questions, and just send question creators to the guides.rubyonrails.org Stop spending time for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the foreign_key the association will be using for `:business_user`:

```
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :business_places
end

class BusinessPlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business_user, :foreign_key => 'BusinessUser_id'
end
```

Comment: Using the :foreign_key is working. My class now is looking like this : class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :BusinessPlaces , :foreign_key => 'BusinessUser_id'
end   with :business_user is not working

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong wording for the keys.  Your models should look like so:

```
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :business_places
end

class BusinessPlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business_user
end
```

so basically use :business_places instead of :BusinessPlaces

if you use migrations to set up your databases you should not need to modify the foreign keys